# CSS/JavaScript slide DIV out and slide DIV in

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

I am wanting to be able to slide a div out (to the left), while sliding another div in (from the right) at the **same time**.

My HTML code is like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="page1">
            <!-- Content Area 1 -->
        </div>
        <div id="page2">
            <!-- Content Area 1 -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Currently I am using

```
document.getElementById('page1').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('page2').style.display = "inline";
```

to switch between the pages, but I would like to have the transition as smooth as possible.

Is there a way I can do this, without jQuery and preferably just in CSS?
If not, how can I do it in jQuery?

Comment: @tymeJV Can you show me how?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head (CSS isn't my game) - but there are plenty of tutorials out there for them

Comment: You want something like a carousel?

Comment: Is it a toggled effect? or when something is clicked, hovered, etc? I tinkered a bit with http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7Qr/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do it with pure css by using `animation keyframes`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="page1" class="page">
        <!-- Content Area 1 -->        
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="page">
        <!-- Content Area 1 -->        
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;    
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.page {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;

    height: 100%;  
    width: 100%;
}
#page1 {
    background: #d94e4e;
    left:-100%;
    -webkit-animation: left-to-right 5s linear forwards;
    animation: left-to-right 5s linear forwards;
}
#page2 {    
    background: #60b044;    
    left:0;    
    -webkit-animation: right-to-left 5s linear forwards;
    animation: right-to-left 5s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes left-to-right{
    from{left:-100%}
    to{left:0}
}
@-webkit-keyframes right-to-left{
    from{left:0}
    to{left:100%}
}

@keyframes left-to-right{
    from{left:-100%}
    to{left:0}
}
@keyframes right-to-left{
    from{left:0}
    to{left:100%}
}
```

**However** there is one huge limitation to this method. CSS can't handle any real events. So if you want this animation to appear when a button is clicked or something, you'll have to use JavaScript.

**Demo** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRfc9/3/)

**Edited**
Now the left one enters and the right one exits at the same time.

**UPDATE** 
The same example using `translate3d` => [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jRfc9/6/)

Comment: This could be easily achieved using translate3d, which will also allow you to tap into a device's GPU for smoother animations.

Answer (score 1):

here's an (almost) full CSS solution:

If you can be more specific about what you want I can happily tweak or guide you through the code to help you.

It relies on using translate3d:

```
transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T4C5z/2/)

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/5EsQk/

```
<div id="content">
         <div id="page1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: white; background-color:silver; float: left; margin-left: -90px;">
             Content Area 1
    </div>
    <div id="page2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; color: white; background-color:silver; float: right; margin-right: -90px;">
        Content Area 1
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page1').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=90"
    }, 5000);
    $('#page2').animate({
        marginRight: "+=90"
    }, 5000);
});
```

edited fiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/5EsQk/1/

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was wanting one div to come in and the other to go out - like the one that is coming in would push the other one out.

Answer (score 0):

Very much possible without jQuery, using only CSS and CSS transitions.

You can set up your CSS so that if `<div id="content">` has no class `.showPage2`, it shows page 1. If it does have `.showPage2`, it shows page 2.

The transition is then only triggered by toggling the class using (native) Javascript. The animation is handled by CSS transitions. This means that if by any change the browser does not support CSS3 transitions, the user will still see the correct page; only not with the fancy transition. CSS3 transitions are generally very smooth.

This is what the CSS would look like:

```
#content
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content #page1
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    transition: left .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-out;
}
#content #page2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    transition: left .5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: left .5s ease-out;
}

#content.showPage2 #page1
{
    left: -100%;
}
#content.showPage2 #page2
{
    left: 0%;
}
```

And the Javascript could look something like this:

```
function showPage1()
{
    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("class", "")
}
function showPage2()
{
    document.getElementById("content").setAttribute("class", "showPage2")
}
```

I hope this handles it in a way that fits your needs.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get this to work; can you give me a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/ne9WC/2/ (click the pages to switch them). Hope it helps!