# how can I collapse (forth and back) a section when I click on a button through JS?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the DOM through JS.
When I click on the button (named collapse all, I want the section below to be collapsed (disappear), but slowly and smoothly ( a transition?), and then when I click again on the same button, I want it to appear again, and so forth...
how can I achieve this through JS?

I wrote this code, but still not working repeatedly , it is working only once :

```
btn_all.addEventListener("click", funct1);
function funct1(e) {
section2.style.transition = "all ease 5s";
section2.style.display = "none";
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
btn_all.addEventListener("click", funct2);
function funct2(e1) {
    section2.style.display = "block";
}
}};
```

the transition is not working...

Comment: here is the page :
https://relaxed-ardinghelli-701d99.netlify.app/

Comment: Perhaps you should add the transition _before_ hiding `section2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS/JavaScript slide DIV out and slide DIV in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044754/css-javascript-slide-div-out-and-slide-div-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? CSS/JavaScript slide DIV out and slide DIV in – 
no !

Answer (score 0):

display: none is instant - you'll want to change some attribute (like height or opacity) and then set display: none when it's done, and put the transition in the base style.

Also, accessibility guidelines (and good taste) generally state that transitions should be fast - give the *impression* of motion, without making them sit through an animation.  250ms is a pretty good speed

E.g.

```
.section {
transition: opacity ease-in .25s;
}

.section.fade-out {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Also, jquery has some simple transitions that generally work unless you're going supernuts in the styles, if that is available. e.g.

```
$(".section2").fadeOut(250);
```

It negates the need for a lot of nullchecking, browser compatibility workarounds, etc. and has a lot of easy shortcuts.  Great for quick development and easy to approach for beginner developers.